# Sqoop import issue - java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but interface was expected

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I'm using `Sqoop 1.4.3` with `hadoop 1.2.4`and `hive 0.11.0`

When I am trying to do a sqoop import: its throwing up `IncompatibleClassChangeError.`

Any suggestions to get this fixed..

Sqoop cmd used:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employees \
    --username test --password test
```

Trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but interface was expected
        at org.apache.sqoop.config.ConfigurationHelper.getJobNumMaps(ConfigurationHelper.java:53)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.config.ConfigurationHelper.getJobNumMaps(ConfigurationHelper.java:36)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat.getSplits(DataDrivenDBInputFormat.java:121)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:1054)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:1071)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$700(JobClient.java:179)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:983)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:936)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:550)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:580)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.doSubmitJob(ImportJobBase.java:173)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runJob(ImportJobBase.java:151)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:221)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:545)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager.importTable(MySQLManager.java:111)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:403)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:476)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:145)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:181)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:220)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:229)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:238)
```

can any one suggest which version of Sqoop we can configure get this working..?

Answer (score 4):

You are suffering from a version conflict, most likely you are running code compiled on Hadoop 1.0 on Hadoop 2.0. This is because Hadoop 1.0 and 2.0 are mostly incompatible, so you should make sure to download the version of Sqoop that matches your Hadoop distribution.

For more details, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14211205/1332690).

Comment: Hey Charles Menguy,

Thank you so much for your reply. I will give it a go. In the mean time do you know any working combination of Hadoop and sqoop distributions so that I would use the same to begin with.

Thanks and Regards,
Nagashree