# Oozie: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected

Tags: hadoop, oozie, sqoop

I am using hadoop 2.7.0, sqoop 1.4.6 and oozie 4.2.0 where all are compatible with hadoop2. I have created a sqoop stored job and i am executing that within oozie. I am trying to import a table with the sqoop incremental append from MySQL to hdfs through the oozie workflow. The job runs successfully when running through the sqoop command line option but getting following error when running the same job through oozie.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
```

Moreover this error is encountered only when sqoop finds some incremental records to be inserted otherwise the workflow runs successfully.

Not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: most likely this is caused due to version mismatches between oozie and the action that you have in your workflow. possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911041/sqoop-import-issue-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror-found-class-org-apa?rq=1

Comment: Yes Thanks was able to solve that..Rebuilding oozie with hadoop 2 solved the issue.